# How to change two select> option dropdown in the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, drop-down-menu

I want that when I select an option from one dropdown,at the same time other  dropdown value should change according to the first one.

For example: if I choose 'Value 1' from 'dropdown 1' , then in 'dropdown 2'
it should change automatically to the same value('Value 1').

Can anyone help-me please? I thank you in advance!

Here is my Demo.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FelipeMartinin/XjuDp/)

```
<select name="" id="">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="">Value 1</option>
  <option value="">Value 2</option>
</select>

<select name="" id="">
   <option value="">Select</option>
   <option value="">Value 1</option>
   <option value="">Value 2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/F8dU9/)</kbd>

```
$(function () {
    var select = $('select.select');
    select.change(function () {
        select.not(this).val(this.value);
    });
});
```

**HTML**

added class select and value to options

```
<select name="" id="" class="select">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="2">Value 2</option>
</select>
<select name="" id="" class="select">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="2">Value 2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4):

First give identities to the selects

```
<select name="" id="one">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="2">Value 2</option>
</select>
<select name="" id="two">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="2">Value 2</option>
</select>
```

Then

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $set = $('#one, #two')
    $set.change(function () {
        $set.not(this).val(this.value)
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9EUys/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I could not make it work = / http://jsfiddle.net/9WgjU/

Comment: You left out all of the ids and values. http://jsfiddle.net/9WgjU/1/

Comment: This is one of the only solutions that has 2 way bindings AND allows you to customize the classes. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

with pure javascript

```
<select name="test1" id="test1">
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="2">Value 2</option>
</select>
<select name="test2" id="test2">
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="2">Value 2</option>
</select>
<script>
document.getElementById('test1').addEventListener("change", function () {
    document.getElementById('test2').selectedIndex = document.getElementById('test1').selectedIndex;
}, false);
</script>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/49FK9/) here..

Answer (score 1):

**Demo:** [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cybercriminal/dJgTf/)

**HTML:**

```
<select name="" id="one">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="">Value 1</option>
    <option value="">Value 2</option>
</select>

<select name="" id="two">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="">Value 1</option>
    <option value="">Value 2</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#one').on('change', function(){
    $("#two option").each(function(){
        if ($(this).text() == $('#one option:selected').text()) {
            $(this).attr('selected',true);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#s1')[0].selectedIndex = 0;
    $('#s1').change(function(){
        var index = $(this)[0].selectedIndex;
        $('#s2')[0].selectedIndex = index;
    });    
});
```

Here's [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hicurin/XjuDp/7/)

Answer (score 0):

You could bind change event for each select. See the demo here:[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XjuDp/6/)

```
    $("#select-1").on("change",function(){
        $("#select-2").val($(this).val());
    })
    $("#select-2").on("change",function(){
        $("#select-1").val($(this).val());
    })
```